# What does ajax GET data look like at the lowest level?

Tags: http, network-protocols

GET requests can be used to retrieve images and text and other things I'm guessing.  There is no need to specify `Content-type`.

What does this data look like at the bit level?  If you are looking at the 1s and 0s in the HTTP packet, what specification governs what can be put here.

Using the client, when I send / receive data via ajax GET, is the data directly transferred into 1s and 0s in the packet or is there some sort of transformation?

For example:

```
xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', config_ajax.url, true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.send(send);

// example data

send = "0xFF";
xhr.responseText = "0x0A"
```

Would one see `11111111` being sent and `00001010` being received if they were analyzing the bit stream?

Comment: Yes, it's the HTTP specification. Read it. Down to the bits and bytes there are some other layers on the network stack, though.

Comment: No, you don't need to read a dictionary - but a book on English grammar does help. And of course does that book not contain how to articulate sounds with your moths, or how to use a pencil to write it down. That's lower level. [HTTP works the same way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http#Technical_overview): "*Its definition presumes an underlying and reliable [transport layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer) protocol*".

Comment: @employee-0 — There's no Request Body, so there is no Content-Type in the request. What comes back is the response, which could have any content type (or no content type for some HTTP statuses).

Comment: So I have access the the pure HTTP bit stream.  I can transfer pure bits as I have shown in the example above?

Comment: Well, I'm just going to test it out...send every bit pattern for 8 bits ( 256 ) and make sure I get it back round trip.  This is better as I don't have to go read a dictionary and possiblly fall asleep at my station. :)

Comment: (Typically), the data is [URL Encoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data) and placed in the URL, which is transmitted over [HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.2), is transmitted over [TCP/IP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) (although there might be some [SSL](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6176.txt) between the HTTP and TCP/IP layers).

Comment: There aren't too many answers ! I'm going to perform the test I mentioned and post it as an answer.  If the data is encoded internally/implicitly I don't care as long as I get my bits back!

Comment: @employee-0: There is no HTTP bit stream, that's what we're trying to tell you. HTTP does not know what comes over the wire (may there's not even a wire?), it just receives data packets from the transport layer.

Comment: you just don't understand what I'm saying when you transfer data between two computers, there is a stream of 1s and 0s.  You could look at it with an O-scope if you wanted to.  Here is good colorful representation of how the ISO-OSI model layers translate down to the bit stream.  http://www.barracudadeals.com/freebies/poster/

Comment: @employee-0: Well, that assumes that the HTTP frames are transferred over TCP/IP/Ethernet, which might be a standard configuration but is not the only possible one. It might look very different and still be HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess there is no need to specify Content-type. What does this data look like at the bit level? If you are looking at the 1s and 0s in the HTTP packet, what specification governs what can be put here.

You're looking for the HTTP specification itself, [section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7). Indeed it works quite like you assumed:

> ## 7 Entity
>
> Request and Response messages MAY transfer an entity if not otherwise
> restricted by the request method or response status code. An
> entity consists of entity-header fields and an entity-body, although
> some responses will only include the entity-headers.
>
> In this section, both sender and recipient refer to either the client
> or the server, depending on who sends and who receives the entity.
>
> In this section, both sender and recipient refer to either the
> client or the server, depending on who sends and who receives the
> entity.
>
> ### 7.1 Entity Header Fields
>
> Entity-header fields define metainformation about the entity-body
> or, if no body is present, about the resource identified by the
> request. Some of this metainformation is OPTIONAL; some might be
> REQUIRED by portions of this specification.
>
> ```
>    entity-header  = Allow                    ; Section 14.7
>                   | Content-Encoding         ; Section 14.11
>                   | Content-Language         ; Section 14.12
>                   | Content-Length           ; Section 14.13
>                   | Content-Location         ; Section 14.14
>                   | Content-MD5              ; Section 14.15
>                   | Content-Range            ; Section 14.16
>                   | Content-Type             ; Section 14.17
>                   | Expires                  ; Section 14.21
>                   | Last-Modified            ; Section 14.29
>                   | extension-header
>
>    extension-header = message-header
> ```
>
> The extension-header mechanism allows additional entity-header
> fields to be defined without changing the protocol, but these
> fields cannot be assumed to be recognizable by the recipient.
> Unrecognized header fields SHOULD be ignored by the recipient and
> MUST be forwarded by transparent proxies.
>
> ### 7.2 Entity Body
>
> The entity-body (if any) sent with an HTTP request or response is
> in a format and encoding defined by the entity-header fields.
>
> ```
>    entity-body = *OCTET
> ```
>
> An entity-body is only present in a message when a message-body is
> present, as described in section 4.3. The entity-body is obtained
> from the message-body by decoding any Transfer-Encoding that might
> have been applied to ensure safe and proper transfer of the message.
>
> ### 7.2.1 Type
>
> When an entity-body is included with a message, the data type of
> that body is determined via the header fields Content-Type and
> Content- Encoding. These define a two-layer, ordered encoding
> model:
>
> ```
>    entity-body := Content-Encoding( Content-Type( data ) )
> ```
>
> Content-Type specifies the media type of the underlying data.
> Content-Encoding may be used to indicate any additional content
> codings applied to the data, usually for the purpose of data
> compression, that are a property of the requested resource. There is
> no default encoding.
>
> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
> Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If
> and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
> recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
> content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
> resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
> treat it as type "application/octet-stream".
>
> ### 7.2.2 Entity Length
>
> The entity-length of a message is the length of the message-body
> before any transfer-codings have been applied. Section 4.4 defines
> how the transfer-length of a message-body is determined.

Comment: HTTP 1.1 is 24 years old...are you sure this is still valid?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 is 14 years old, only the idea started in 1989. And yes, it still works. And it even will work like that in [HTTP/2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_2.0), where the semantics of HTTP/1.1 [still apply](http://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#HTTPLayer) with only a few changes, like the body being transmitted as a separate [`DATA` frame](http://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#DATA).

Comment: Ten years to develop a standard.  Long time.